# Difference between boost::split vs boost::iter_split

Tags: c++, boost

What is the difference between `boost::split` and `boost::iter_split` functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`boost::split` copies the split string into the `SequenceSequenceT` (for example, a `std::vector<std::string>`). `boost::iter_split` places `iterators` (specifically, iterator ranges) into the `SequenceSequenceT`.

This effectively means two things:

1. Using `split` will create copies, hence any changes to the returned container of strings won't be seen by the original string. Also, you don't need to worry about iterator invalidation.
2. Using `iter_split` will give back a container of iterator ranges, hence, modifying what these iterators point to will also modify the original string. Secondly, if the original string is modified after you run `iter_split`, you could run into iterator invalidation issues. However, no copies are performed on the underlying string, so this will likely run slightly faster and use less memory.

Comment: This doesn't seem right, given https://github.com/boostorg/algorithm/blob/develop/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp#L146 (`split` doesn't do anything besides calling `iter_split`).