# How to use boost::split with boost::string_ref in boost 1.55

Tags: c++11, boost

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>

int main() 
{
    boost::string_ref str = "test_the_world";
    std::vector<boost::string_ref> strs;
    boost::split(strs, str, boost::is_any_of("_"), boost::token_compress_on);
    for (auto& v : strs)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
1>C:\boost_1_55_0\boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp(643): error C2665: 'boost::basic_string_ref<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_string_ref' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>          C:\boost_1_55_0\boost/utility/string_ref.hpp(79): could be 'boost::basic_string_ref<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_string_ref(const charT *,boost::basic_string_ref<charT,std::char_traits<char>>::size_type)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              charT=char
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const char *, const char *)'
1>          C:\boost_1_55_0\boost/algorithm/string/detail/util.hpp(97) : see reference to function template instantiation 'SeqT boost::copy_range<SeqT,boost::iterator_range<const char *>>(const Range &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              SeqT=boost::basic_string_ref<char,std::char_traits<char>>
1>  ,            Range=boost::iterator_range<const char *>
1>          ]
1>          C:\boost_1_55_0\boost/algorithm/string/detail/util.hpp(96) : while compiling class template member function 'boost::basic_string_ref<char,std::char_traits<char>> boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<boost::basic_string_ref<char,std::char_traits<char>>,input_iterator_type>::operator ()(const boost::iterator_range<const char *> &) const'
```

Etc .. how can I make this work? Can't see why it shouldn't work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Boost  `iter_split` is well suited for this, although it naturally favours `iterator_range` instead of `string_ref`: [Difference between boost::split vs boost::iter_split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781090/difference-between-boostsplit-vs-boostiter-split)

```
using R = boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator>;
using V = std::vector<R>;
V v;

for (auto&& r : iter_split(v, input, token_finder(is_any_of(";"))))
    std::cout << r << "\n";
```

If you insist you can adapt the result:

```
for (string_ref&& r : iter_split(v, input, token_finder(is_any_of(";"))) 
    | transformed([](R const& r){return boost::string_ref(&*r.begin(), r.size());})
    std::cout << r << "\n";
```

Or if you don't have c++11 support:

```
for (string_ref&& r : iter_split(v, input, token_finder(is_any_of(";"))) 
         | transformed(phx::construct<boost::string_ref>(&*phx::begin(_1), phx::size(_1))))
    std::cout << r << "\n";
```

Combine with `copy_range<vector<string_ref> >()` if you want a real vector of `string_ref` objects.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7e615660ee8f29a)**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/finder.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/stl.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::algorithm;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
using namespace phx::arg_names;
using boost::adaptors::transformed;

int main() {
    std::string input = "1;3;5;7";

    using boost::string_ref;
    using R = boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator>;
    using V = std::vector<R>;
    V v;

    // just the iterator ranges:
    for (auto&& r : iter_split(v, input, token_finder(is_any_of(";"))))
        std::cout << r << "\n";

    // using a lambda to create the string_refs:
    for (string_ref&& r : iter_split(v, input, token_finder(is_any_of(";"))) 
            | transformed([](R const& r){return string_ref(&*r.begin(), r.size());}))
        std::cout << r << "\n";

    // c++03 version:
    for (string_ref&& r : iter_split(v, input, token_finder(is_any_of(";"))) 
            | transformed(phx::construct<string_ref>(&*phx::begin(_1), phx::size(_1))))
        std::cout << r << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Definitely the "clean" answer, *+1*.

Comment: @sehe I realize it's a bit late but just wanted to point out that your C++03 version is not really C++03. I tried to adapt it but it still fails (with `boost::phoenix` http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5O5T4SUufyPRpx6E

Answer (score 6):

Cheap hack: Specialize `copy_range` for `string_ref`, because it doesn't take an iterator pair.

```
namespace boost
{
    template <>
    inline string_ref
    copy_range<string_ref, iterator_range<char const*>>
      ( iterator_range<char const*> const& r )
    {
        return string_ref( begin(r),  end(r) - begin(r) );
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c539c13f1d66f68).

However, there are certainly far better solutions to this, so I'll keep looking.

Comment: Mmm. I'm really torn on this. Copying ranges really should not do user defined transformations (beyond the implicit conversions people will expect from the documentation). Then again, this is quite elegant. I've created the more traditional type of solutions in my answer for comparison